# How to refresh registry keys without reboot?

Tags: delphi, registry, delphi-7

I use the following code to change region data in the Registry.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  reg: TRegistry;
begin
  reg:=TRegistry.Create;
  try
    reg.RootKey:=HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
    reg.OpenKey('\Control Panel\International\',true);
    reg.WriteString('iCountry','1');
    reg.WriteString('iCurrDigits','2');
    reg.WriteString('iCurrency','0');
    reg.WriteString('iDate','1');    
    reg.WriteString('iDigits','2');         
    reg.WriteString('iLZero','0'); 
    reg.WriteString('iMeasure','1');    
    reg.WriteString('iNegCurr','0'); 
    reg.WriteString('iNegNumber','1');    
    reg.WriteString('iTimePrefix','0'); 
    reg.WriteString('iTLZero','1');    
    reg.WriteString('Locale','00000409');        
    reg.WriteString('LocaleName','en-US');    
    reg.WriteString('sCountry','United States');    
    reg.WriteString('sDate','/'); 
    reg.WriteString('sDecimal','.');    
    reg.WriteString('iNegCurr','0');    
    reg.WriteString('sShortDate','dd/MM/yyyy'); reg.CloseKey;
  finally    
    reg.free; 
  end; 
end;
```

but this requires restarting the machine before the changes take effect. Can it be done without rebooting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After changing the Registry, broadcast a system-wide [`WM_SETTINGCHANGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725497.aspx) message by calling [`SendMessageTimeout()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644952.aspx) with its `hWnd` set to `HWND_BROADCAST`:

> Applications should send WM_SETTINGCHANGE to all top-level windows when they make changes to system parameters.
>
> ...
>
> wParam
>   ... When the system sends this message as a result of a change in locale settings, this parameter is zero.
>
> When an application sends this message, this parameter must be NULL.
>
> ...
>
> lParam
>   ... When the system sends this message as a result of a change in locale settings, this parameter points to the string "intl".

For example:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  reg: TRegistry;
begin
  reg := TRegistry.Create;
  try
    reg.RootKey := HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
    reg.Access := KEY_SET_VALUE;
    if reg.OpenKey('\Control Panel\International\', true) then
    try
      reg.WriteString('iCountry','1');
      reg.WriteString('iCurrDigits','2');
      reg.WriteString('iCurrency','0');
      reg.WriteString('iDate','1');    
      reg.WriteString('iDigits','2');         
      reg.WriteString('iLZero','0'); 
      reg.WriteString('iMeasure','1');    
      reg.WriteString('iNegCurr','0'); 
      reg.WriteString('iNegNumber','1');    
      reg.WriteString('iTimePrefix','0'); 
      reg.WriteString('iTLZero','1');    
      reg.WriteString('Locale','00000409');        
      reg.WriteString('LocaleName','en-US');    
      reg.WriteString('sCountry','United States');    
      reg.WriteString('sDate','/'); 
      reg.WriteString('sDecimal','.');    
      reg.WriteString('iNegCurr','0');    
      reg.WriteString('sShortDate','dd/MM/yyyy');
    finally
      reg.CloseKey;
      SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, LPARAM(PChar('intl')), SMTO_NORMAL, 100, PDWORD(nil)^);
    end;
  finally    
    reg.free; 
  end; 
end;
```

And before you ask, yes it is safe to use `nil` in the last parameter in this manner:

[Passing nil to a variable parameter](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/23006)

Prior to XE2, Delphi's `Windows` unit declares the last parameter of `SendMessageTimeout()` as:

```
var lpdwResult: DWORD
```

But the Win32 API defines the parameter as:

```
_Out_opt_ PDWORD_PTR lpdwResult
```

Which allows a NULL pointer to be passed in.  The above `nil` trick is the only way for Delphi code to pass a NULL value to a `var` parameter.  The machine code generated by the compiler will be correct - it will simply pass a value of 0 to the parameter, it will not actually try access memory address $00000000.

In XE2, the `Windows` unit was changed to declare the last parameter as:

```
lpdwResult: PDWORD_PTR
```

To match the Win32 API definition.

So, if you ever upgrade your code to XE2 or later, simply replace `PDWORD(nil)^` with `nil` instead.  Or, you can account for it now and not worry about it later:

```
SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, LPARAM(PChar('intl')), SMTO_NORMAL, 100, {$IF RTLVersion >= 23}nil{$ELSE}PDWORD(nil)^{$IFEND});
```

Comment: but I use your existing code error: Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical

Comment: @Ahmad either give up, or read the code, understand the error, and work out how to fix it. Just because somebody writes some code in an answer does not imply that they have to debug your program when you transfer the code there. The error message is clear. Do you understand it?

Comment: The most likely explanation is the final arg of SendMessageTimeout. Read the declaration in Windows.pas and see if you can work it out.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan according to [one of your own answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20958416/65863), what I showed should compile. I will have to look at it when I get to my dev computer

Comment: @remy Could be a change in the Windows unit. Asker here is D7. I think that the asker should be able to work this out.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: you are right. In D7, `SendMessageTimeout()` is declared as this: `function SendMessageTimeout(hWnd: HWND; Msg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM; fuFlags, uTimeout: UINT; var lpdwResult: DWORD): LRESULT; stdcall;` The parameter was changed from `var DWORD` to `PDWORD_PTR` in XE2.

Comment: Ty sir is working, srry sir 
I'm just a student progmmer